# Word order in "either/or" parallel structure

Tags: word-order

Does it matter where *either* goes in this *either/or* sentence, and do I need to repeat *from* in *or from* if I've used *either from*?

> Air pollution may come **either from** the ocean as natural contaminants given off by sea life **or from** the internal combustion engines of automobiles.
>
> Air pollution may come **from either** the ocean as natural contaminants given off by sea life **or** the internal combustion engines of automobiles.

Comment: I hope I've identified the problem here. In order to help avoid closure for proof-reading (no guarantees there, though!) you need to explicitly state what you are unsure about. If I've got it wrong, please edit again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have difficult understanding which sentence is correct?The first one extracted from a book and I changed the second one.I just want to know that my sentence is correct as well?

Comment: Yes: but what is it about each sentence which you are unsure of? You need to be **absolutely specific.** Which part of the sentence are you wondering is correct? I've assumed it's *either/or* and the position/duplication of *from*. If I have that right, fine. But it might not be. Your comment about the source is valuable and should go in the question; but "Is it correct?" is proof-reading and the question will be summarily closed.

Comment: I've assumed it's either/or and the position/duplication of from. If I have that right, fine." Yes YOU ARE RIGHT."

Answer (score 1):

While both sentences are correct, the second is preferable because it eliminates repeating the word *from*. It would be a different story if you needed different prepositions, but you don't.

Look at it very logically and almost mathematically with two correct examples:

"Either *from* A or *into* B." I used *into* to show another preposition besides *from*. Since the *either* serves as a fork before mention of A or B, you need insert a preposition for each.

"From either A or B." That idea means from A and from B. Since the *either* serves as a fork after you mentioned *from*, the word *from* applies to both A and B. (Notice I did not say *to A* and *to B*.) Do not insert a preposition for each unless the sentence is so long that most readers will forget their place.

So if you need two prepositions, that works well to set up the parallel construction. If you do not, have the single preposition apply to both A and B by placing it before the *either.*

Similar parallels: I *love both* my father and mother.  I *both love* and admire Pat.