# "Either" in a positive sentence

Tags: british-english, word-order, either-or

1. You have **either** betrayed me **or** you have thought of doing it.
2. **Either** you have betrayed me **or** you have thought of doing it.

Which of these two sentences is correct?

Comment: I'd go with 2. For parallelism, 2 has "Either YOU did X, or YOU did Y."  However, 1 has "YOU have EITHER X, or YOU have Y."  Since 'either' introduces a fork in the road, the choices need to match.  To fix that: "You have either (Betrayed me) or (Thought of doing it)."  I put the X and Y elements in parens.

Comment: Related: [Word order in “either/or” parallel structure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/369598), [“Should either be” or “should be either”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9123),

Comment: Also related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9123/112436

Comment: "I'm *positive* you've either betrayed me or thought of doing it."

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct, and you may want to try reading your paragraph out loud (ideally, to a live human being), in the two versions, to see which one feels like it flows more to your liking.

If you want to, you could make Sentence 1 a bit more succinct:

> You have either betrayed me or thought of doing it.

Here's what the [Oxford dictionary says about word order with *either*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/either):

> In good English writing style, it is important that either and or are correctly placed so that the structures following each word balance and mirror each other. Thus, sentences such as *either I accompany you or I wait here* and *I'm going to buy either a new camera or a new video* are correct, whereas sentences such as *either I accompany you or John* and *I'm either going to buy a new camera or a video* are not well-balanced sentences and should not be used in written English.

Note: in my opinion, even in cases where two word orders are possible, there are some situations where the reader might be more likely to get a slightly different meaning from one word order or the other.  But this is not one of those cases.

Comment: ***You have either betrayed me or you have thought of doing it.*** Paradoxically this first sentence (which some purists may consider technically incorrect) sounds better and 'flows' more naturally than the second, which is grammatically correct but feels stiff and rather pompous - do you agree?

Comment: @EnglishStudent - I think that what you said about some purists is a matter that deserves its own question, and if it hasn't been addressed yet, would be a good one to ask; but I will say here that I agree with what you said about the flow vs. the pomposity for this particular sentence.

Answer (score 1):

the word "either" would be comparing two things in a positive way

him: "Would you like a hamburger or a hotdog?" 
her: "Either would be fine"

the word "neither" would be comparing two things in a negative way

him: "Would you like a hamburger or a hotdog?" 
her: "Neither, I would like a sandwich"

the word "nor" would also be used in a negative way

him: "Would you like a hamburger or a hotdog" 
her: "I would not like a hamburger nor a hotdog"